# Is method a subset of a properties in javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, methods, properties

In learning javascript through JavaScript The Definitive Guide, I saw

> When the value of a property is a function, we call it a method.

Q1. Is method a subset of properties?

A1. Yes.

---

Q2. When a variable, like string and number (NOT Object), is declared, does it inherit property from String or Number Object?

A1. Variable is just a reference.

Comment: A property is a property. The value of a property, like the value of a variable, may be a reference to an object, a number, a string, `null`, or a reference to a function (special case of reference to an object), or various other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q1. Are methods a subset of properties?

Yes. When the value of a property is a function (or, strictly, a reference to a function), it's usually called a method of the object. It also infers that the method should be called to set its *this* to the object:

```js
var global = this;
var obj = {
  fn: function() {
    console.log('this is ' + (this == obj ? 'obj' :
      this == global? 'global' : this)
     );
  }
};

// Call as method of obj
obj.fn();

// Call as plain function
var f = obj.fn;
f();
```

> Q2. When variable, like string and number(NOT Object), be declared, Does it inherit property from String, Number Object?

Variables do not have a type, their values do. Declaring a variable simply creates it as a reference within the relevant context (note that [*var*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) behaves differently to [*let*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) and [*const*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)).

It might appear that a variable has a type, but it's the value that has the type:

```js
var a;
console.log('a is : ' + typeof a); // undefined
a = "A";
console.log('a is : ' + typeof a); // string
a = 5;
console.log('a is : ' + typeof a); // number
```